# Matplotlib Event Handlers not being Called when Embedded in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

## Overview

I am in the process of embedding a Matplotlib plot in a Tkinter window. I need to use the Matplotlib event handler functions (described [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html)). When run as a standalone Matplotlib figure, I get the correct behavior: the event handlers perform their correct function on the correct user action. But when embedding in a Tkinter window, the Matplotlib event handlers are no longer being called.

### Expected Behavior

The Matplotlib event handler should be called when the figure is embedded in a Tkinter window.

### Current Behavior

The Matplotlib event handler is not being called.

### Minimal Code Snippet

#### Without Tkinter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onpick(event):
    print("You selected the line!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    ### MATPLOTLIB SETUP ###
    xs = [0,1,2] #x-values of the graph
    ys = [4,3,2] #y-values of the graph

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.plot(xs, ys, picker=True)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

    plt.show()
```

When this code is run, you can select the line on the plot and the `onpick` method is called, printing the text to `stdout`. This is the desired output.

#### Embedded in Tkinter

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onpick(event):
    print("You selected the line!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    ### MATPLOTLIB SETUP ###
    xs = [0,1,2] #x-values of the graph
    ys = [4,3,2] #y-values of the graph

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.plot(xs, ys, picker=True)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

    ### TKINTER SETUP ###

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
    
    tkinter.mainloop()
```

When this code is run and you try to click on the line, the text is never printed meaning the `onpick` method is never being called.

### Versions

- `python` : 3.6.1
- `matplotlib` : 3.3.4
- `tkinter` : 8.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listeners of the Matplotlib `Figure` object cannot be called when embedded in Tkinter. Instead, you have to add the listeners to the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` (or similar) object. So a working example built on the previous minimal example would be:

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onpick(event):
    print("You selected the line!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    ### MATPLOTLIB SETUP ###
    xs = [0,1,2] #x-values of the graph
    ys = [4,3,2] #y-values of the graph

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.plot(xs, ys, picker=True)

    #plt.show()

    ### TKINTER SETUP ###

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

    canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", onpick) # Add the listener using this command

    tkinter.mainloop()
```